# Excel VBA: Error 1004 trying to set a value to range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weird bug trying to create a small macro. I want to create a value for a specific cell, that is a function. However when i try to do that, it gives me error 1004.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Systems").Range("C" & c.Row).Value = "=CELL(" & Chr(34) & "row" & Chr(34) & ";Articles!A" & c.Value
```

Articles is just another sheet.
The `Chr(34`) is just a `"` char.

This line gives me the error. Now, I tried to replace the special characters with `Chr` commands.

The following line doesn't give me an error

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Systems").Range("C" & c.Row).Value = Chr(61) & "CELL"
```

But this one does:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Systems").Range("C" & c.Row).Value = Chr(61) & "CELL" & Chr(40)
```

`Chr(61)` is a `=` and `Chr(40)` is a `(`.

Can somebody please show me a way to work around this? I would be very glad. Using Ofiice 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Just double the quotes `""` inside a string:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Systems").Range("C" & c.Row).Formula "=CELL(""row"",Articles!A" & c.Value & ")"
```

Also note that you should use `.Formula` to write a formula in standard US-English format or `.FormulaLocal` to write a formula in your localization format.

It is recommended to use the standard US format and `.Formula` as this will work world wide.
Standard US format uses `,` and not `;` as separator in formulas. If you have difficulties translating formulas use https://en.excel-translator.de